# How can i make customizable views on IOS ? (i used style.id as a parameter on android view class constructor)

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, swiftui

First I want to talk about what I exactly did on Android, and I am now trying to do the same on IOS :

- I developed a library on Android which contains an activity, in that activity we have several type of views (labels, buttons ... etc).
  These views are used as an entry point/inputs for my library that provides some services to other apps.
- To be able to match the general style of the user app, I created my own View Classes, the user(of my library) needs to provide a style id to the activity before launching it, so it can be used when constructing the View.
- Doing so, we are able to maintain the style of the app without the need to re-implement the views for every app that uses my library or making the user(final user on physical device) feels as if he just moved out to another app.

I am really a newbie on iOS and I recently started to learn it so i am not sure how to do it, can you please provide me some guidelines please?

On iOS there are so many ways to create views (xibs, Storyboards , SwiftUI, and programatically). I am not really sure where to start.

He's a sample of my code on Android :

```
class MyView(val context: Context, val themeId: Int) : View(context) {
    init {
     val wrappedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeId)
     val mInflater = wrappedContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
     mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view_layout, this, true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but the short answer is "sure, it can be done."

I suppose a quick example might be:

- I have a custom `UIView` with a `UILabel` centered in it, with 20-pts padding on all 4 sides.
- I have 4 "themes" defined, defining the view's background color, the label's text color and the label's font style.
- I write a custom init func to accept an Int "id" of 1 through 4
- The library user could then instantiate it along the lines of `let myView = MyView(with themeId: 2)`

As this is a very broad question (topic), once you start developing your custom view you could come back if you run into specific coding questions.